# Why does padding affect the outer size?

Tags: css

I arrived at the following look.

[image]

Noticing that the text is placed above the green markers, I decided to add some **inner** padding to the three pinkish containers. When I've done as I'd decided, it came up like this, to my greatest surprised and disappointment.

[image]

Why is the **outer** size affected by the **inner** padding?! I've padded boxes when shipping stuff. They don't get bigger just because I put those white thingies inside to protect the contents! I just get less space inside...

Does it have to do with the strange spacing **between** my *DIV*'s? I can't get rid of these neither...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the W3C box model:

```
totalWidth = marginLeft + borderLeft + paddingLeft
             + width
             + paddingRight + borderRight + marginRight
contentWidth = width
```

Microsoft's one is much more intuitive:

```
totalWidth = marginLeft + width + marginRight
contentWidth = width - (borderLeft + paddingLeft + paddingRight + borderRight)
```

To use IE model, you can use CSS3 `box-sizing`:

```
*, :before, :after { box-sizing: border-box; }
```

Also see [`box-sizing`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) in MDN, and [Internet Explorer box model bug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_box_model_bug) in Wikipedia.

Comment: Isn't that going to limit my users to IE only? I prefer to provide equal hospitality for all my visitors.

Comment: @KonradViltersten No, you can make modern browsers behave like IE quirks mode using `box-sizing: border-box`. This is recommended by [Paul Irish](http://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/), an expert in web technologies like HTML5 and CSS3.

Comment: And just to be clear - the style you mention is supposed to be added to the three components constituting the insides, not the outer one containing them. Correct?

Comment: @KonradViltersten Yes, because `box-sizing` isn't inherited, and you want it to affect each inner element (because the extra width is caused by borders and paddings in inner elements).

Answer (score 1):

[Box-sizing](http://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/) is a CSS3 property you can use to get the padding to affect the inside of the element.

It can be useful to have the padding to affect the outside for some reasons but ofcourse padding on the inside should be standard.